# Save Chronoforms Data to External MS SQL DB

Tags: php, joomla, chronoforms

I created a form with `Chronoforms5` . Now I'm trying to save data in an external database that runs on MS SQL . I do not know if the action SaveDB saves on MS SQL . I tried to set it so it does not work .

[image]

How can I do? With a Custom code ?

Answer (score 1):

Joomla! doesn't have a database driver called MSSQL, I think that you need sqlsrv to connect to a MS SQL Server. if that doesn't work then it would require a hand-coded connection in a Custom Code action.

FYI: I have seen other reports of problems with the sqlsrv library and there were some reported problems with ChronoForms v5 and some MS SQL queries.